# How to add an application as Firewall exception in WiX installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, wix-extension

I have an installer with large number of files to install. I'm using heat.exe to harvest all the files. This heat command is actually a part of my build script followed by other commands like Candle.exe and light.exe. Now my application test.exe is also harvested with auto-generated GUID and component ID. How can I add this particular application as firewall exception. The problem is that every time I'll build installer using the script, a new harvest file will be generated with new component IDs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you add a customaction as a script with `netsh advfirewall fitewall add `  like described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709)

Comment: Actually I am thinking to try WiXFirewallExtension. http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/firewall_xsd_firewallexception.htm

Comment: Is the fileid stable in your situation? In that case you can indeed use that extension.

Comment: This is the problem. Actually the field is not stable. Heat is referring to a folder that contains all the files to be installed. And application is under some phase of change so every time there will be some different version of application in that source directory

Answer (score 1):

`heat` accepts an XSL transform argument to modify its output in any way you need. A simple XSL stylesheet can add an element to a particular `File` element selected via XPath.

This assumes that there is only `test.exe` in your `heat` run. If that's not the case, modify the XPath in the `match` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'
    xmlns:fire='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension'
    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'
    exclude-result-prefixes='wix'
    >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="//wix:File[contains(@Source,'\test.exe')]">
    <wix:File>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <fire:FirewallException Id='test.exe' Name='Test Server' IgnoreFailure='yes'>
        <xsl:comment> localhost won't work here </xsl:comment>
        <fire:RemoteAddress>127.0.0.1</fire:RemoteAddress>
      </fire:FirewallException>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </wix:File>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:comment>!!!DO NOT EDIT!!! Generated by heat.exe and FirewallExceptions added.</xsl:comment>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is something wrong. I'm prosting my output for the file below
<wix:File Id="filB43E5AB85E71C8F538EB2EDE3CCAF77D" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.TestDir)\Test.exe" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:fire="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension"><fire:FirewallException Id="Test.exe" Name="Test Server" IgnoreFailure="yes"><!-- localhost won't work here --><fire:RemoteAddress>127.0.0.1</fire:RemoteAddress></fire:FirewallException></wix:File>

Comment: Don't let the placement XML namespace prefix declarations (xmlns:...) bother you; The XSL processor can put them anywhere that has the same semantic meaning for the output document. If you think something else is wrong, please post that output in your question—It's mangled and/or incomplete in the comment.